# Reproduce the table of Exercise 22.7 in the TeXbook

Tags: tables

In Exercise 22.7 of TeXbook, a special table is created using `\halign` with templates:

```
\def\welshverb#1={{\bf#1} = }
\halign{\welshverb#\hfil\tabskip=1em plus 1em&
  \welshverb#\hfil&\welshverb#\hfil\tabskip=0pt\cr
  rydw i=I am& ydw i=am I& roeddwn i=I was\cr
  rwyt ti=thou art& wyt ti=art thou& roeddet ti=thou wast\cr
  mae e=he is& ydy e=is he& roedd e=he was\cr
  mae hi=she is& ydy hi=is she& roedd hi=she was\cr}
```

[image]
What's the easiest way to reproduce this table in modern LaTeX fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do even better, with an input syntax less crowded than Knuth's.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\welshverb}{m}
 {
  \stephen_welshverb:w #1
 }
\cs_new:Npn \stephen_welshverb:w #1 =
 {
  \textbf{#1}\unskip\ =\ \ignorespaces
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *{3}{>{\collectcell\welshverb}l<{\endcollectcell}} @{}}
  rydw i  = I am     & ydw i  = am I     & roeddwn i  = I was \\
  rwyt ti = thou art & wyt ti = art thou & roeddet ti = thou wast \\
  mae e   = he is    & ydy e  = is he    & roedd e    = he was \\
  mae hi  = she is   & ydy hi = is she   & roedd hi   = she was
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, a question on which my L3 code uses higher abstraction level than yours... :P

Comment: Nice! I forgot the `w` type argument specifiers. :(

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that preserves Knuth's definition of `\welshverb`, apart from the minor change from `\bf` to `\bfseries`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}
\def\welshverb#1={{\bfseries #1} = }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{>{\welshverb}l} }
  rydw i=I am& ydw i=am I& roeddwn i=I was \\
  rwyt ti=thou art& wyt ti=art thou& roeddet ti=thou wast \\
  mae e=he is& ydy e=is he& roedd e=he was \\
  mae hi=she is& ydy hi=is she& roedd hi=she was 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And how about the definition of `\welshverb`? Can we also change it? For those who don't read TeXbook, maybe they hardly know that we can use `=` as the delimiter of the parameter in this way.

Comment: @Stephen - You asked for "the easiest way" to port the plain-TeX code to LaTeX; I assumed there was a reason for why you didn't ask for "the most idiomatic way". Using `\def` in a "modern LaTeX" document is entirely legitimate. There's definitely nothing old-fashioned, let alone deprecated, about using `\def`.

Comment: I for one prefer this solution with `\def` over the L3 approaches - I find it much more readable and intuitive.

Comment: @Marijn - Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use some highlevel language for the task, you could use the `collcell` package for grabbing the entire cell contents, and use an l3 implementation to split on equals signs.

This allows to put optional spaces before and after the equals sign in the input without altering the output (with the plainTeX solution you'd get doubled spaces).

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\welshverbcell{m}
  {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF {#1} { = }
      {
        % implementation here assumes just one = is present at top level (else
        % everything after the second equals sign is lost)
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { = } {#1}
        \exp_args:Nee \welshverbformat
          { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 1 }
          { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 2 }
      }
      {#1} % ignore cells not containing an equals sign
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\welshverbformat { m m }
  {%
    \textbf{#1} = #2%
  }
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{>{\collectcell\welshverbcell}l<{\endcollectcell}} }
  rydw i=I am& ydw i=am I& roeddwn i=I was \\
  rwyt ti=thou art& wyt ti=art thou& roeddet ti=thou wast \\
  mae e=he is& ydy e=is he& roedd e=he was \\
  mae hi=she is& ydy hi=is she& roedd hi=she was 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```